# Everything compiles, but Resharper marks everything in red?

Tags: resharper

I'm using VS 2008 with Resharper 5.1

Al of a sudden, Resharper shows all classes etc I use in red. As if I didn't refecrence the correct project/dll.

BUT: everything is referenced, and the code compiles.

What is going on and how can I solve this?

I already tried this: deleted the _ReSharper-folder and deleted the 5.1.ReSharper.user-file

Comment: Do you have solution-wide analysis enabled, or not? Did you restart Visual Studio (or at least close and reopen your solution) after deleting the _ReSharper.* folder?

Comment: No, I did not restart VS. But apparantly, I had to delete the .suo-file as wel.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try deleting the .suo file as well.

Comment: Worked for me even in VS 2013! The only difference is there is no _ReSharper folder.

Comment: And for me in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 43):

The solution that worked for me was to clear re-sharper cache and suspend & resume re-sharper.

```
Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Re-sharper > General > Options > General > Clear Caches

Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Re-sharper > General > Suspend Now > Resume Now
```

Comment: agreed, the .suo was not enough to fix the issue but doing the above worked like a charm

Comment: I can't find the second option in ReSharper

Comment: Clear Caches PLUS deleting the .vs folder worked for me

Comment: While maybe the other one might work for some. This should be the answer